# Make predictions with final keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**Context:**

let's say I had a sequence of length 100. 70 for training and 30 for testing with no shuffling. I used the training set for creating/fitting the model as follows:

```py
model = fit_lstm(train_scaled, batch_size,nb_epochs, nb_neurons)
```

And for testing:

```py
forecast = model.predict(test_reshaped, batch_size=batch_size)
```

**Issue:**

Now that I have my final model saved and loaded elsewhere, I would like to predict what comes after (future predictions) using:

```py
prediction = model.predict(X, btach_size=batch_size)
```

However, I don't know what to feed the model as X? Should X be similar to training set or test set in length, transformations(scaling,differentiating), etc? How far can the model can go in the future?

Comment: Yes! X will be as similar as you have created training set. Apply the same pre processing on test set which will be your X.

Comment: My predictions go as far as 10 months ahead. Next month's predictions seem fair and after that less accurate. When I collect next month's REAL data, is it better to retrain the model before making predictions about the month after that?

Comment: Yes, it would be better to retrain the model after obtaining next month's data. Deep learning rely's a lot on the data.